# Teamcity - Perform Git Fetch for Agent-Side Checkout

Tags: teamcity, gitversion

I am trying to perform a full `git fetch` from my build agent, in order to use [GitVersion](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion) in TeamCity.

I have opted to use the agent checkout option in TeamCity, as per http://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build-server-support/build-server/teamcity/#agent-checkout

However, when I perform a checkout on the agent, I'm unable to get the full git history for a branch. I get the same result as this: https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/912 - Specifically:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a 'develop' or 'master' branch, neither locally nor remotely.

My guess is this is because TeamCity is only checking out a subset of the repo history.

The Github issue has a workaround of performing a `git fetch` command at the start of every build. Is this something that TeamCity can natively support as part of a VCS root?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Anyone got a solution to this yet?   Yes, I'm specifying the /output buildserver option.   And it never happens on the original build server, only on the new build agent that I just spun up.  The original one is running on the same machine as TeamCity if that matters.  Running Team City version 2017.2.3 (build 51047) if that matters.

Comment: If I go to that build directory and type the git fetch --all and then run gitversion it works correctly, however, because we remove the folder on a new build, this doesn't solve the issue - unless we wanted to add it as a build step to every project we have!  Clearly, the other build server has something this one lacks.

Comment: running the latest gitversion on the new build server: 4.0.0+Branch.master.Sha.e715eb5dd515037d90a257f527e62442cae8c1c5 .  On the old build server, it is a version before /version worked.

Comment: According to Chocolatey  (choco version gitversion) they are both 1.0.0.1, so clearly, the fact that they don't function the same is weird..

Answer (score 2):

TeamCity has the ability to fetch all heads TeamCity since v2017, but needs to be enabled via a config setting.

You can configure Git-plugin to fetch all heads by [adding a build configuration parameter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/configuring-build-parameters.html#Defining-Build-Parameters-in-Build-Configuration):

`teamcity.git.fetchAllHeads=true.`

See here for more details:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/git.html#Git-GeneralSettings
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-24878
- https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/912

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the command line arguments that you are passing to GitVersion when running on TeamCity?  Are you specifying the `/output buildserver` option?  When this is enabled, GitVersion goes through a branch normalisation process, to ensure that all required branches are fetched from the repository.

Comment: Effectively, that is part of what I described. The normalisation process is about ensure that all git information is available locally, so that the correct version number can be asserted.

Comment: I'm confused, I tried adding a build step to do a git fetch --all (and it tried to popup a login prompt to get credentials, so it failed to work - not sure how to fix that), but if I go to the build directory where the build failed and run the gitversion there, I get an error.  if I then run git fetch --all, then gitversion it works.  How can I fix this so it works?  (Open to *any* fix at this point - I have a 20 build configurations that fail, and one that works (it doesn't use gitversion due to not being able to rebuild without checking in changes so I dropped it for my builds)

Comment: so, yes, after running the gitversion /output buildserver I can see that I have branch x and remote/x as the only branches.  if I git fetch --all, then I see branch x, and remote/x, remote/y, remote/z.. (lots and lots of them) . so it seems like the getversion /output buildserver didn't fetch anything, and I need something else to kick it?